# Função recursiva Python

Tags: python, recursão

Eu preciso construir uma função recursiva em Python que receba um inteiro **n** e imprima até zero e em seguida volte a **n**.
Exemplo: n = 5; > 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5

Até então construí uma função, mas ela só imprime `5 4 3 2 1`:

```
>>> def regressive(n):
...   while(n):
...     print(n)
...     n = n - 1
...   print('hello!')
...
>>> regressive(5)
5
4
3
2
1
hello!
```

Alguém sabe como faço para retornar a **n** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essa função que você escreveu não é recursiva! 
Recursão é quando uma função chama ela mesma. Você escreveu uma função iterativa.

Olhe esse código:

```
def Recursiva(n):
  if n == 1:
    print(n)
    return 
  print(n)
  Recursiva(n-1) 
  print(n)

Recursiva(5)
```

Resultado:

```
5
4
3
2
1
2
3
4
5
```

Toda função recursiva deve ter um critério de parada, no caso o critério é que o parâmetro n que está sendo passado seja 1.

Então quando você chamar a função Recursiva pela primeira vez e passar um numero como parâmetro, ele vai verificar se esse numero é 1, se for ele imprime e retorna a função, se não for ele printa o numero e chama a Recursiva com n-1. Na hora que o critério for atingindo, as chamadas de função vão sendo retornadas e terminando o resto da função onde foram chamadas. Imprimindo os números aumentando de valor.

Ficou claro?

Comment: Entendido! Muito obrigada!